# Cannot use react bootstrap with class component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a class component that I am trying to style the elements, the buttons, textboxes etc. To those ends I followed this link https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction to install bootstrap in my react then i have `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';` and `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in my header.
.

If I use `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` I notice that my button has no style at all and looking at examples I see everyone using `<Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" disabled>Test</Button>` except that, when I do I get the error `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` Since I am using a class component, does that mean I have to rewrite the entire thing to a function? But also I see the example on this link https://www.golangprograms.com/how-to-use-react-bootstrap-component.html using a class.

Appreciate if I be assisted in this regard.

Regards

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class Transport extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            dieselTxt: '',
            electricTxt: '',
            gasolineTxt: '',
            vehMaintain: '',
            gasolineCarbon:''
        }
    }
    handDieselChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            dieselTxt: event.target.value
        })
    }
    handElectricChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            electricTxt: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handGasTxtChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            gasolineTxt: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handBusTxtChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            BusTxt: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handTrainTxtChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            trainTxt: event.target.value
        })
    }


    handFlightTxtChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            flightTxt: event.target.value
        })
    }
    handVenSelectChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            vehMaintain: event.target.value
        })
    }

    vehiclesCarbon = (event) => {
        alert("test");
        if (`${this.state.vehMaintain}` === '1') {

            //` 22 / miles per galon(21.6) )* EF_passenger_vehicle*(nonCO2_vehicle_emissions_ratio)`
            const estLBCarbonGas = ((this.state.gasolineTxt / 21.6) * 19.6* 1.01).toFixed(0);
            this.setState({ gasolineCarbon: estLBCarbonGas })
        }
        
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    render() {
        const { dieselTxt, electricTxt, gasolineTxt, vehMaintain, gasolineCarbon,trainTxt, BusTxt, flightTxt } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Enter your vehicle's yearly milage</h4>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <div>
                        <label>Gasoline </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={gasolineTxt}
                            onChange={this.handGasTxtChange}
                        />
                    </div>


                    {/* <div>
                        <label>Diesel</label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={dieselTxt}
                            onChange={this.handDieselChange}
                        />

                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>Electric</label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={electricTxt}
                            onChange={this.handElectricChange}
                        />
                    </div> */}

                    <div>
                    <label>Do you perform regular maintenance on your vehicle?</label>
                    <select value={vehMaintain}
                        onChange={this.handVenSelectChange}>
                        <option value=""></option>    
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                        <option value="2">No</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input type="text"
                            value={gasolineCarbon}
                            
                        />
                    </div>

                    {/* <p>Public Transporation</p>

                    <div>
                        <label>Bus </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={BusTxt}
                            onChange={this.handBusTxtChange}
                        />

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Train </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={trainTxt}
                            onChange={this.handTrainTxtChange}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <p>Air Travel</p>
                    <div>
                        <label>Flights </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={flightTxt}
                            onChange={this.handFlightTxtChange}
                        />
                    </div> */}
                    <div>
                    <button onClick={this.vehiclesCarbon}>Test</button>
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" disabled>

Primary button

</Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Transport
```

Tab

```
import { useState } from "react";
import EnergyConsum from "./EnergyConsum";
import Transport from "./Transport";
import WasteForm from "./WasteForm";
//import "./App.css";

function Tabs() {
    const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);

    const toggleTab = (index) => {
        setToggleState(index);
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="bloc-tabs">
                <button
                    className={toggleState === 1 ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}
                    onClick={() => toggleTab(1)}
                >
                    Energy Consumption
                </button>
                <button
                    className={toggleState === 2 ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}
                    onClick={() => toggleTab(2)}
                >
                    Transport
                </button>
                <button
                    className={toggleState === 3 ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}
                    onClick={() => toggleTab(3)}
                >
                    Tab 3
                </button>
            </div>

            <div className="content-tabs">
                <div
                    className={toggleState === 1 ? "content  active-content" : "content"}
                >
                    <h5>How much energy do you consume</h5>
                    <hr />
                    <EnergyConsum />
                </div>

                <div
                    className={toggleState === 2 ? "content  active-content" : "content"}
                >
                    <h2>How do you get around</h2>
                    <hr />
                    <Transport />
                </div>

                <div
                    className={toggleState === 3 ? "content  active-content" : "content"}
                >
                    <h2>Content 3</h2>
                    <hr />
                    <WasteForm />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tabs;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; 
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

 
reportWebVitals();
```

Full Error Message

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
▶ 21 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
H:/Documents/Projects/Solidity/MYCFC/my-cfc/src/index.js:8
   5 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; 
   6 | 
   7 | 
>  8 | ReactDOM.render(
   9 |   <React.StrictMode>
  10 |     <App />
  11 |   </React.StrictMode>,
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:2365:30
__webpack_require__
H:/Documents/Projects/Solidity/MYCFC/my-cfc/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
H:/Documents/Projects/Solidity/MYCFC/my-cfc/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:2501:18
__webpack_require__
H:/Documents/Projects/Solidity/MYCFC/my-cfc/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
H:/Documents/Projects/Solidity/MYCFC/my-cfc/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
H:/Documents/Projects/Solidity/MYCFC/my-cfc/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:65
```

Comment: Can you post your component? The bootstrap component is more than likely not at fault here.

Comment: @Baruch Pasted the entire component

Comment: Copy/pasted into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cannot-use-react-bootstrap-with-class-component-fkbwx) and I don't see an issue.

Comment: @DrewReese When I run it says "×
`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`

Comment: @Baruch I should also mention that this component is passed to my Tabs and then that is passed to the app.js

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the code

Comment: Added your new code to codesandbox, and still no error. What version of React are you running? Are you sure you are running the latest version of your code changes? In other words, make sure you kill any running development servers and maybe even do a git clean of your local repo and `npm install`, and try restarting/rebuilding your app.

Comment: @DrewReese That's crazy, I'm running react 17.0.2, stopped the server and started and all...no change...oh well..

Comment: @DrewReese I believe it's pointing to my index.js ` ReactDOM.render(` as  having the error

Comment: Can you add the full error message and stacktrace to your question?

Comment: @DrewReese Added

Comment: The error is that you have different versions of react. That's why it's pointing to webpack.

Comment: @Baruch How Can I locate it and handle it. package-lock.json is 17.0.1, so is the react.development.js file and results from `npm view react version`